# Measuring thread idle time with TBB

Tags: tbb, benchmarking

I have a threaded application with timing blocks around all the sections of code I *believe* are performance intensive.  These sections are long enough that the timing code can remain active even in final production runs.  The application has a bunch of worker threads pulling work from a task pool.

In my current custom pool implementation, I compute two extra times for each worker thread: (1) the amount of idle time spent waiting on an empty pool for a job to arrive and (2) the amount of "missing" time not accounted for by either idling or a timing block (indicating a performance intensive region that I've missed).

I'm now considering switching my code over to Intel Thread Building Blocks.  Is it possible to measure idle time when using TBB tasks?  The sum of idle time and missing time can easily be computed by subtracting each timed section from the total wall clock interval, but getting at each separately requires special support (or perhaps a special idle task with low priority that spins trying to preempt itself?).

Note: I also asked this question at http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=107203, and will synchronize any answers.

Comment: If this is running on Windows you can find this information out with either the Windows Performance toolkit (Win8 SDK) or the Concurrency Visualizer in VS2010+.

Comment: I want this to work during production runs on 50k-100k cores (using both MPI and threads), so Windows doesn't apply.

Comment: How does your current custom pool implementation schedule tasks?  As TBB uses work stealing, worker threads don't really 'wait' for tasks - they go and steal them from other threads (assuming there are any tasks currently available).  The only time a thread should be idle is during imperfectly parallelised or serial code.  Of course it would still be nice to measure this!

Comment: As you say, worker threads definitely do wait for tasks, which indicates imperfectly parallelized code.  If you have suggestions for how to always get perfect speedup, I'd be happy to entertain them!  My code is here for reference: https://github.com/girving/pentago